# Who initialize the variables of interface in java?

Tags: java

Since there is no constructor in Interface, who initialize the variables of interface in java?

Comment: You cannot create an instance of an interface. You can only create an instance of an implementer of that interface, a *concrete class*. Additionally, an interface cannot have members, by definition.

Comment: @Michael: you seem to be using an uncommon meaning of “members”. An interface *can* have members, as methods and constant fields are members. Even nested types are members.

Comment: @Holger My bad. I meant 'fields'.

Answer (score 3):

Java uses implicit modifiers for `interfaces`. So the interface:

```
 public interface I {
     String FIELD = "Some field";

     void method();
 }
```

Can in fact be written as:

```
public interface I {
     public static final String FIELD = "Some field";

     public abstract void method();
}
```

Then you see that the fields in an interface all are `public static final` and the methods `public abstract`.

Because the field is `static final` and `static-initializer-blocks` are not allowed in interfaces it has to be initialized directly and thus no constructor is used.

Answer (score 2):

This btw is no different than a `public static final` variable inside a class too - it will not be initialized by the constructor, since well, it's a `constant` - as `javap` outputs it **ConstantValue**.

```
 class Test {
      public static final int x = 5; // ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
                                     //   ConstantValue: int 5

      public int y = 3; // putfield , initialized inside default constructor 
 }
```

**EDIT** Holger is right in his comment that there *can* be initialization code within a static block. For example having a class:

```
class C {

}
```

That has a reference in an interface:

```
interface Test {
    C c = new C();
}
```

would result in a static block at compile time that would look something like this:

```
interface Test {

    C c;

    static {
        c = new C();
    }
}
```